# Unable to pip install package (Permission Denied)

Tags: python, pip

Here is the issue, everytime I am trying to use pip to install package, I have an [Error 13]: permission denied issue.

I think that the versions of pip and python installed on my computer are a bit of a mess, here is what I have when typing:

```
python -V
Python 3.6.8

python2 -V
Python 2.7.12

python3 -V
Python 3.5.2

pip --version
pip 19.2.3 from /home/geoffrey/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip (python 3.5)

pip3 --version
pip 19.2.3 from /home/geoffrey/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip (python 3.5)
```

I would like to fix all of this and make it clear, can someone help please ?

Thank you !

Comment: Try `sudo pip install package` if you're on osx/linux

Comment: @byxor Using pip under sudo for package installation is not recommended

Comment: Have you tried `<python version> -m pip install package`, e.g. `python3 -m pip`?

Comment: When typing pip install package, without sudo, here is what i get:

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1

Comment: And with `python3 -m pip install package` I have the error:

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-fkzmbjnk/package/

Any ideas ?

Comment: If you don't want to sudo, you can install the package locally with `pip install --user package`. This shouldn't require extra permissions

Comment: Well in the environment created I can used pip, but not iPython, I have the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'decorator'`. And the second I leave the environment the errors come back.
Also, if I try using the `sudo pip install package`, I have the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'`